# python script in rc.local won't start at boot

Tags: python, startup, bashrc

This is what I've put in rc.local:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/lz/DynDnsUpdater/DynDnsUpdater.py &>> /home/lz/DynDnsUpdater/log &
```

It's supposed to redirect every output to the log file and run at background so the system does not hang at startup. However, I see no output in the file, and `ps -e | grep python` won't give me anything.

The python file is a loop that never fails because it has try catch in everything, so it never ends, so it should always be running.

What is wrong?

Comment: If you are using a systemd-based version of Ubuntu, make sure that the `rc-local.service` is enabled. Also `&>>` is a "bashism" - AFAIK `rc.local` is executed by `/bin/sh`

Comment: @steeldriver so how should I redirect the output in sh? I enabled rc-local.service and this is its status after: `Condition: start condition failed at Sun 2018-10-28 18:52:50 -02; 15s ago
           └─ ConditionFileIsExecutable=/etc/rc.local was not met`

Comment: Make `/etc/rc.local` executable:  `sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

Comment: @muru it worked. Do you know how can I redirect the output?

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` is run using `/bin/dash`, not bash, so `>> /home/lz/DynDnsUpdater/log 2>&1` instead of `&>> ...`, I suppose.

Comment: @muru do I still need to put & in the end for it to run in the background?

Comment: @muru whenever I try to run with `>> path 2>&1` I get that I don't have permissions for the path